# How to build PyQT project?

Tags: windows, pyqt, py2exe

I have a simple PyQT project. I would like to know how to build it in Windows in such way, that it becomes runnable executable. I don't want to require user to install heavy QT framework for his computer. How to make executable with only necessary parts of QT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use `py2exe` for deploying a Windows standalone GUI cross-platform (under Linux, all the python libs are available on the Linux hosts).  You run the py2exe "setup" to build an .exe+, and py2exe pulls the binary bits and your python code and builds into a loadable, runnable Windows executable pack.

Python 2.5 on windows was the long-time requirement, but the recent [0.6.9 release](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=640751&group_id=15583) added python2.6 (and python2.7?) support.  No python3 yet.

Also, you may want to consult [Py2exeAndPyQt](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt) on py2exe wiki.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to py2exe and cx-Freeze, check out PyInstaller.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at py2exe, cxFreeze or other python packaging apps? They weed out the needed dlls by looking at what you use.